# WebSeeding Transmssion Client

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I want to make a torrent file with web seed enable. Where is can find this setting in Transmission bitorrent client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out `buildtorrent` to create a file. **Buildtorrent** provides Webseed functionality.

To install **buildtorrent**:

```
 sudo apt-get install buildtorrent
```

Usage:

```
  buildtorrent [OPTIONS] -a http://tracker.yoursite.com input output
  buildtorrent [OPTIONS] -a http://tracker.yoursite.com -f filelist -n name output
```

To enable Webseed option

```
--webseeds        -w  <webseeds>   : webseed url list (format: a,b,c)
```

Comment: any gui ? I need gui version

Comment: The `deluge` torrent client has a graphical interface to create torrents with web seeds.

Comment: `mktorrent` is an other command line tool to create torrents that supports web seeds.

Answer (score 0):

Transmission-create is a  command-line utility to create .torrent files.

The syntax for the comnnad is as follows

```
transmission-create -p <use it only if private tracker> -o <filename.torrent> -c <comment> -t <Tracker> <source file or directory of files you want share>
```

Comment: where is web seed option in this?